# Payment Integration in NodeJS, React, MongoDB website

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, payment-gateway, payment

I am developing Online quiz application, where admin creates the quiz and users attempt the quiz by registering and paying some money. Now admin wants to send winning money to the top 5 winners in one click by seeing their result. so how these can be implemented ?

Do I need to develop e wallet of user or is there any third party API/package/library/gateway to solve this problem?

Please provide some links/videos/tutorials/blogs related to this question?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api
refer this

Comment: https://blog.risingstack.com/stripe-payments-integration-tutorial-javascript/